# Open HTML file with Google Chrome using command-line

Tags: bash, google-chrome

In default installation of macOS, Python and Bash are installed in `/usr/bin` and `/bin` directories respectively.

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ which bash
/bin/bash
```

So it's appropriate files can be opened using the command-line as:

```
python foo.py
```

Along similar lines, I want the ability to open an HTML file with Google Chrome using the command-line as:

```
$ chrome foo.html
```

But I get the following output:

```
bash: chrome: command not found
```

An alternate way to achieve the desired workflow is make Google Chrome as the default browser and execute the following command:

```
open foo.html
```

How do I achieve the former workflow?

Comment: for your own scripts you can add a folder such as `~/bin` to your `PATH` variable, or use `/usr/local/bin` which normally is user-writable on macs. And btw, `open path/to/file.html` should work without problem, provided that you allowed chrome to take over the extensions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no need to create or copy any file into `/usr/bin` directory. A simple solution would be create an alias as shown below:

`alias chrome="open -a \"Google Chrome\"`.

Now you open the HTML file as you described by executing:

`chrome foo.html`

You may wish to export the alias to make the behaviour permanent placing the alias in `.bash_profile` in your home directory.

Comment: ty, how to export alias to make it permanent?

Comment: Updated the answer with instructions on how to export the alias.

Comment: I add the alias to ~/.bash_profile `$ chrome foo.html
-bash: chrome: command not found`.Still, I should manual  reset alias when restarting the terminal.

Comment: the command above is incomplete, it should be:
`alias chrome="open -a \"Google Chrome\"."`
then remember to run:
`source .bash_profile`

Comment: Command above need the end `"`: `alias chrome="open -a \"Google Chrome\""`

Answer (score 8):

`/usr/bin` is a system directory owned by root user and it isn't possible to create any files in it due to Apple's [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204899) introduced in Mac OS X El Capitan.

The command you are looking for is:

`open -a "Google Chrome" foo.html`

Description of command:

`open -a "ApplicationToUse" file-to-open.extension`

More details on the `open` command via `man open` on the command line.

In general, the above command-line can be used to launch any GUI app to open associated file.

`open` command is built into macOS. For more `open` command tips and tricks, refer this article, [Shell tricks: the OS X open command](http://brettterpstra.com/2014/08/06/shell-tricks-the-os-x-open-command/).